# How to get UUID for a USB drive?

Tags: command-line, mount, usb

I want to mount my USB to a mount point which holds the UUID name. But I don't know how to express this in a command line!

Can someone help me how to do it?

I have searched and found that I have to run:

```
blkid
```

then a command which searches for a USB flash or hard disk drive, then something like

```
blkid | tail -n 1 | cut -f4 -d' '
```

but `tail` is wrong because I don't know the number of USB I have!

Is there a way to tell it to just get me the lines with USB type?

Comment: here's the answer . I found it my self by trial and error:

    sudo blkid | tr -s ' ' | grep 'TYPE="vfat"' | cut -f4 -d'"' | sed -n "p"

sed ! can't under stand it :S

Comment: Your `sed -n "p"` is redundant, it just prints what it gets unaltered, like `cat`.

Answer (score 20):

Reading the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/blkid) shows you can use options to get what you want:

```
blkid -t TYPE=vfat -sUUID
```

gives (for me):

```
/dev/sdb: UUID="50CA-8C03"
```

#### Extract the UUID

- You can extract the UUID with `cut -d'"' -f2`:

  ```
  blkid -t TYPE=vfat -sUUID | cut -d'"' -f2
  ```

  The `blkid` options are preferable because a USB drive can have e.g., a label which would give a different output as with plain `blkid` invocation.
- Or, `blkid` can do what you want on its own:

  ```
  blkid -t TYPE=vfat -sUUID -ovalue
  ```

Answer (score 1):

> Asked 9 years, 11 months ago

consider using the `lsblk` command using options.  For example

```
alias lsblk2='lsblk -o size,fstype,model,name'
alias lsblk3='lsblk -o size,fstype,model,name,serial,uuid'
```

All the options for `lsblk` after the `-o` can be found via `lsblk --help`

I have settled on those two aliases, which I make for myself in my .bashrc, to facilitate identifying disks.  It seems to give me all the relevant info I could want.

From that you would have the necessary information of every disk that's connected.  And then you have what you need to use the mount command.  The `mount` syntax being for example

```
mount /dev/sd?   /myusbdisk

# or

mount UUID=whatever  /myusbdisk
```

Using `wwn` as a mount option might also be useful fwiw.

all the -o options:

```
Available columns (for --output):

NAME  device name
KNAME  internal kernel device name
MAJ:MIN  major:minor device number
FSTYPE  filesystem type
MOUNTPOINT  where the device is mounted
LABEL  filesystem LABEL
UUID  filesystem UUID
PARTLABEL  partition LABEL
PARTUUID  partition UUID
RA  read-ahead of the device
RO  read-only device
RM  removable device
MODEL  device identifier
SERIAL  disk serial number
SIZE  size of the device
STATE  state of the device
OWNER  user name
GROUP  group name
MODE  device node permissions
ALIGNMENT  alignment offset
MIN-IO  minimum I/O size
OPT-IO  optimal I/O size
PHY-SEC  physical sector size
LOG-SEC  logical sector size
ROTA  rotational device
SCHED  I/O scheduler name
RQ-SIZE  request queue size
TYPE  device type
DISC-ALN  discard alignment offset
DISC-GRAN  discard granularity
DISC-MAX  discard max bytes
DISC-ZERO  discard zeroes data
WSAME  write same max bytes
WWN  unique storage identifier
RAND  adds randomness
PKNAME  internal parent kernel device name
HCTL  Host:Channel:Target:Lun for SCSI
TRAN  device transport type
REV  device revision
VENDOR  device vendor
```